# Manipulate Mac OS X file icons from Automator or command-line

Tags: macos, terminal.app

Is there a way to manipulate icons on an Mac OS X file from either Automator or the terminal?

In my case, I want to remove custom icons (that is, the same as doing 'Get Info' and Edit->Cut on the icon) from a large number of files.

Comment: By the way, please accept answers to your old questions if they were answered. Everything here works off reputation points given by selecting the check mark next to answers. You can view old questions in your profile.

Answer (score 9):

I asked this question back in 2007. A combination of 3 OS X tools can do this. You need Developer Tools installed, then check out: /Developer/Tools/Rez, DeRez, and SetFile.

You can use 'sips' to give an image file a custom icon of itself ('sips' acts on the original file so it might be safer to work on a copy):

```
/bin/cp imagefile.jpg donorfile.jpg
/usr/bin/sips -i donorfile.jpg
```

If you just wanted to give an image file a thumbnail custom icon of itself, you can stop there.

Otherwise, if you have the "Developer" / "X Code" tools installed, you can use 'DeRez' and 'Rez' to manipulate the resources to copy the newly created 'icns' resource to a file:

```
/Developer/Tools/DeRez -only icns donorfile.jpg > tempicns.rsrc
```

Then copy the the temp file into the icns resource of the recipient file, and set the custom icon file attribute:

```
/Developer/Tools/Rez -append tempicns.rsrc -o recipientfile.xyz
/Developer/Tools/SetFile -a C recipientfile.xyz
```

Finally, restart the "Finder" to view the changes:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to quit' -e 'delay 2' -e 'tell application "Finder" to activate'
```

Original question and answer thread: http://forums.macosxhints.com/showpost.php?p=372418&postcount=7

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about Automator, but it's possible from [Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29) using

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:nil
                               forFile:@"/path/to/file"
                               options:0];
```

or as a simple Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from AppKit import NSWorkspace
import sys

for path in sys.argv[1:]:
    NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().setIcon_forFile_options_(None, path, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the python script.  I made a version to extract the icon as jpeg

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# python script that extract an icon from an OSX file and save it at jpeg

from AppKit import *
import sys

for path in sys.argv[1:]:
NSBitmapImageRep.imageRepWithData_(NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().iconForFile_(path).TIFFRepresentation()).representationUsingType_properties_(NSJPEGFileType, None).writeToFile_atomically_(path+".jpg", None)
```

Answer (score 0):

`xattr` would remove the custom icon if the file has a metadata associated with it, as I have tried removing the metada and it only removed the custom icon. However, please check if you have other metada associated with the file besides the custom icon in the `com.apple.Finder` tag. The way to do it is:

```
xattr -d com.apple.Finder filename
```

For more options:

```
xattr --help
```

You can check if the file has associated `xattr` to begin with if you find the `@` mark just after the permissions using `ls -l` on the file. Again, I had nothing besides a custom icon associated with the file and the above command removed it neatly, maybe your file has more than just the custom icon associated with this tag. I am not an expert on metadata.